# DataGrid RowDetails?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid` that show list of items, each item maybe has detail, this is my code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgItemsReceipt" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ocItemsinInvoice,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item" Binding="{Binding Item.ItemName}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding SalePrice,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qnt" Binding="{Binding Quantity,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False"  />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemsInInvoiceChoices.ChoicesId}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

ItemsInInvoiceChoices is a related table with ItemsinInvoice.

Now when I add Item and add Choice for it, the Item appeare in the Data Grid but the detail now appeare?

Comment: i thing this wrong `Text="{Binding ItemsInInvoiceChoices.ChoicesId}"`, paste code of  Model of your `ocItemsinInvoice`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name" Binding="{Binding Item.ItemName}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding SalePrice,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=ocChoiceRecord, ElementName=myRoot}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RecordDescription}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I updated my code. The relativesource must be at the Listbox itemssource-binding

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, I'm thinking if I could filter the observablecollection ? is this good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

What is `myRoot` here? You dont need to give `ElementName` here. If `ocChoiceRecord` is the property of item of `ocItemsinInvoice` collection. You can directly bind it like below. In this way, each row detail will be bound to its Item.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ocChoiceRecord}">
```

Comment: I tried but it's driving me crazy, please can you help me to figure this issue

Comment: trying the answer displayed the row details?